# How to assign default value to the member variable of embedded class in an entity using lombok?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I have an embedded class in my entity. To set the default values for method variables, I've used lombok builder default. But for embedded class, it is not applying.

**Entity Class**

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
@Builder
class EntityClass{

  @Builder.Default
  private String someVariable = "";

  @Embedded
  private Address address;

}
```

**Embedded Class**

```
@Embeddable
@Data
@Builder
class Address{

  @Builder.Default
  private String someVariable = "";

  @Builder.Default
  private String someOtherVariable = "";

}
```

For **Address** default values are not applying and I'm getting null if I don't set values.

Comment: please add the code that creates the EntityClass with builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `@Builder.Default` requires a value to be assigned. In normal cases, we used to assign like,

```
@Builder.Default
private String someString = "";

@Builder.Default
private Integer someInteger = 0;
```

In the same manner `Address` needs to be initialized.

I've used the builder in embedded class.

```
@Embedded
@Builder.Default
private Address address = Address.builder.build();
```

It works!

Answer (score 1):

If you are instantiating the `EntityClass` using its builder and while setting the field with type `Address`, you are using `Address.builder()` then the default values will be assigned with their default values.

For example:

```
EntityClass entity = EntityClass.builder().address(Address.builder().build()).build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think assigning the object in entity class would be meaningful in order to handle default values for all the instance.